# PHP recursively turning an ArrayObject to an Associative Array

Tags: php, oop, recursion, callback, arrayobject

Hey guys I have a method that is supposed to call back and recursively turn an `Arrayobject` into an associative array, unfortunately I'm getting a fatal error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method ArrayObject::toArray()
```

Here's my method

```
/**
 * Take an ArrayObject and recursively turn it into an array
 * 
 * @param bool $recursion
 * 
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($recursion = false) 
{
    // just in case the object might be multidimensional
    if (true === $this->object) return $this->object->getArrayCopy();

    return array_map( function($item)
    {
        return is_object($item) ? $item->toArray(true) : $item;

    }, $this->object->getArrayCopy() );
}
```

And here's a sample `ArrayObject`

```
ArrayObject Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [profile] => ArrayObject Object
                (
                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                        (
                            [list] => ArrayObject Object
                                (
                                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [location] => 
                                            [network_name] => 
                                            [interests] => 
                                            [last_name] => 
                                            [url] => 
                                            [significant_other] => 
                                            [network_domains] => 
                                            [contact] => ArrayObject Object
                                                (
                                                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [im] => ArrayObject Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [provider] => 
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                            [email_addresses] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [messages] => ArrayObject Object
                (
                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                        (
                            [list] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => foo
                                    [1] => bar
                                    [2] => baz
                                )

                        )

                )

            [groups] => ArrayObject Object
                (
                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [users] => ArrayObject Object
                (
                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: where and how you are calling the function toArray function.

Comment: In another class I am instantiating my parser, parsing an input, assigning that value(s) to `$this->object` then running `$foo = $bar->toArray()`. The typical way of instantiating and utilizing  public method calls.

Comment: try with change the name of function replace toArray() to other. And second thing is, as the error, you are creating the object of parser. you are calling function by the object of array. recheck your code.

Comment: The point of creating the callback was making this recursive, changing the name of the callback to `getArrayCopy()`. Using `getArrayCopy()` instead of `$this->toArray()` breaks the recursive functionality and only operates on the top layer of the object.

Comment: don't use getArrayCopy() name. I am saying replace with anyother name.

Comment: @GauravVashishtha that didn't work.

Comment: are you using class to define the function in your parser?

Comment: Yes its a class defined function

Comment: and are you creating the proper way to create the abject of class to call the function?

Comment: Yeah its correctly created, the issue lies in that methods callback procedure. It can't reference `self::` or `$this` since its inside `array_map()` where neither really exist. I believe its a scoping issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works correctly, by passing `$this` as a variable I don't need to worry about colliding with `$this->object` or scope issues.

```
/**
 * Public wrapper for Protected getArray()
 * 
 * @return arrau
 */
public function toArray()
{
    return $this->getArray($this->object);
}

/**
 * Take an ArrayObject and turn it into an associative array
 * 
 * @param ArrayObject $obj
 * 
 * @return array
 */
protected function getArray($obj) 
{
    $array  = array(); // noisy $array does not exist
    $arrObj = is_object($obj) ? get_object_vars($obj) : $obj;
    foreach ($arrObj as $key => $val) {
            $val = (is_array($val) || is_object($val)) ? $this->getArray($val) : $val;
            $array[$key] = $val;
    }
    return $array;
}
```